# ethernet issue QualComm Atheros AR8151

Tags: windows-8.1, ethernet

I have a strange issue with windows 8.1, I'm trying to connect with an Ethernet cord. In Network Connections it states:

```
Ethernet
Do Not Use
Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 PCI-E...
```

I cannot get online obviously, I tried the diagnose function but nothing was returned, restarted everything multiple times, reinstalled the drivers. The weird part is that when I login to my router on a different computer I can see this one as connected.

Any ideas?

Thanks